# GAE go only serves paths on localhost not domain

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am messing around with a small go app for google app engine locally using the appengine sdk.

I have a problem where a path different than root can only be served if I try to hit it using localhost, but not a domain name.

My setup is as follows.

- home.mydomain.com points to my home ip adress
- My home router forwards incoming tcp and udp on port 80 to my laptop on port 8080
- My laptop is running Windows 10
- My go version is go1.6 windows/amd64

My app.yaml:

```
application: tasks
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url:  /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Minimum example code:

```
func init() {
    fileHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("../frontend"))

    http.HandleFunc("/loggedout", testHandler)
    http.Handle("/", fileHandler)

    log.Print(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func testHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){    
    panic("JUST NEED THIS TO WORK")
}
```

My symptoms is that if I access localhost:8080/ I get my website, and if I access localhost:8080/loggedout I get the expected panic.
If I access home.mydomain.com/ I get my website, however if I access home.mydomain.com/loggedout the connection just hangs, in chromes network tab it is listed as pending indefinitely.

Comment: Are you running using the App Engine SDK? (goapp or dev_appserver?) Your code shouldn't be calling ListenAndServe if so. And if not, then this isn't an app engine question...

Comment: Thanks alot Greg you where right, I did not need to ListenAndServe. However once I removed that nothing worked when I accessed via home.mydomain.com/ but that was because I didn't listen for it, so I added --host 10.0.0.2 to my command and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greg pointed out, when I was using goapp I did not need to also call ListenAndServe.
To get goapp to listen for requests outside of localhost I also had to add --host "my laptops ip" to the command.